# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SRWebSocket"

Tags: objective-c, websocket, compiler-errors, armv7, socketrocket

I'm using SocketRocket as a WebSocket library which I have installed through the cocoabot package manager in a MAC for a platform with iOS 6.

When in appDeligate.m I put the header files

```
#import <SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.h>
```

and in a function I'm using:

```
SRWebSocket *_webSocket
_webSocket.delegate = nil;
[_webSocket close];

_webSocket = [[SRWebSocket alloc] initWithURLRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"ws://192.168.178.178:6001"]]];
_webSocket.delegate = self;

NSLog(@"Opening Connection...");
[_webSocket open];
```

In a standalone project this works quite fine, however when I include it in my project I receive the following error:

> Ld
>   /Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.app/myProject
>   normal armv7
>       cd /Users/devuser/Documents/cordovadev/myProject
>       export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
>       export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang
>   -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS9.2.sdk
>   -L/Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos
>   -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Users/devuser/Library/Developer/GStreamer/iPhone.sdk -filelist /Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myProject.LinkFileList
>   -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -dead_strip -lresolv -lstdc++ -framework CoreAudio -framework AudioToolbox -framework VideoToolbox -framework
>   OpenGLES -framework AssetsLibrary -framework QuartzCore
>   -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak_framework CoreMotion
>   -weak-lSystem -force_load /Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   -ObjC -fobjc-link-runtime -framework GStreamer -lresolv -weak_framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework OpenGLES /Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a
>   -liconv -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -framework ImageIO -framework OpenAL -framework AssetsLibrary -framework
>   Foundation -weak_framework UIKit -framework CoreGraphics -framework
>   AddressBook -framework AddressBookUI -framework AudioToolbox
>   -weak_framework AVFoundation -framework CFNetwork -framework MediaPlayer -framework QuartzCore -framework SystemConfiguration
>   -framework MobileCoreServices -lPods-myProject -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Intermediates/myProject.build/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.build/Objects-normal/armv7/myProject_dependency_info.dat
>   -o /Users/devuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myProject-fxqgbeafqfsypwclwioqqupwexue/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/myProject.app/myProject
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SRWebSocket", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
>
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

I've checked around but I couldn't find anything relevant. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

I had to link the socket library into the Build Settings.

Project->Build Settings->Other Linker Flags->Debug/Release I added

-ObjC
-l SocketRocket
-l icucore
-framework CFNetwork
-framework Security

and now it's working!